# button parece não estar no DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Boa noite, tenho uma tabela jquery onde em uma coluna eu retorno um botão

```
{ "data" : 'sla.value', 'render': function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
  return ' <button id="show" type="button">Click</button>'; }
```

Depois de fechar o`});` da tabela vem um simples alerta (todos dentro do $(document).ready):

```
 $('#show').click(function(){
  alert('oi');
   });
```

Mas ao clicar não acontece nada, se inspecionar o botão ele aparece o id **show**. A mesma coisa acontece se eu colocar assim `onclick="metodo();"` direto no elemento e criar esse método em baixo, no console informa que 'método' não foi encontrado. Alguma idéia? Parece simples mas estou empacado nisso. vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu botão está sendo criado dinamicamente. Geralmente quando queremos encontrar esse tipo de elemento no DOM, usamos isso:

```
$(document).on('click', '#show', function(){
    alert('oi');
})
```

#### Exemplo atribuindo o evento ao elemento da sua forma antes de criá-lo:

Veja que não vai funcionar.

```js
$('#show').click(function(){
 alert('oi');
});
$('body').append('<button id="show" type="button">Click</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Exemplo atribuindo o evento ao elemento da outra forma mesmo antes de criá-lo:

Veja que agora vai funcionar.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#show', function(){
   alert('oi');
})
$('body').append('<button id="show" type="button">Click</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Veja se funciona no seu caso.